# How can I get my program (converting numbers to their textual representation) to work?

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm trying to allow the user to input the string and for my program to return the corresponding number.  For example, if the user types "one", the program returns "1" and so on.  I'm attaching what I have built so far, but I am stuck and I've been at this for two days after work - any advice is greatly appreciated!  I know the last line is incorrect, but I'm hoping that I'm going in the right direction to make this work.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Scanner;

class HTDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // creates a Hashtable <key, value>
        Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

        // adds values to the Hashtable
        numbers.put("one", new Integer(1));
        numbers.put("two", new Integer(2));
        numbers.put("three", new Integer(3));
        numbers.put("four", new Integer(4));
        numbers.put("five", new Integer(5));
        numbers.put("six", new Integer(6));
        numbers.put("seven", new Integer(7));
        numbers.put("eight", new Integer(8));
        numbers.put("nine", new Integer(9));
        numbers.put("ten", new Integer(10));

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a string value 'one' through 'ten': ");
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered: " + line + numbers.containsKey(object));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, besides the standard observations that you should use `Map` and `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`, you shouldn't do everything in `main`, and you don't need or want to use `new Integer`, you have reversed the direction of the map.  According to the problem statement, when the user types `1`, you want the program to print out `one`.  So, you want something like:

```
private Map<Integer, String> numbers;
private final Map<Integer, String> initializeNumberMap() {
    numbers = new HashMap<>();
    numbers.put(1, "one");
    ...
    numbers.put(10, "ten");
    return numbers;
}
```

Call that in the constructor of the `HTDemo` class and have your `main` create an instance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HTDemo().run();
}
public HTDemo() {
    initializeNumberMap();
}
public void run() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input a number between 1 and 10 inclusively.");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    if (number >= 1 && number <= 10) {
        System.out.println("You entered " + numbers.get(number);
    } else {
        System.out.println("I don't understand " + number + " yet.");
    }
}
```

Now, a research project for you would be to handle all integers, so that `-5` leads to `"minus five"`.  Note that languages other than English have major differences in number names and cases.  Also, if you want to do more than write a command-line application; if you want to write a utility for your other problems, you will want to look at caching and concurrency. But that's for another day.

## Why not Hashtable?

`Hashtable` and `Vector` are old and obsolete. Each method of these classes are `synchronized`, so they are slower than `HashMap` and  `ArrayList`.  No one uses these any more, so you shouldn't.

## Why not main?

If you do everything in `main`, you cannot test your work.  Suppose you wanted to do that research project and you wanted to test your code.  You would probably extract a method `String convertToString(int number)`.  And then you could write JUnit tests to check that `convertToString(17) == "seventeen"`

## Why not new Integer(n)?

Since `Integer`s are immutable, there is never a need to make more than one with the same value.  You can explicitly get a `Integer` with that value with `Integer.valueOf(n)`.  It might be a new one, or it may have been one already created.  Small `int`s always lead to a cached value.

But, you almost never need to do this.  Java has *autoboxing*, where `int`s are converted to `Integer`s as they are needed.  The statement

```
numbers.put(1, "one");
```

silently converts `1` to `Integer.valueOf(1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not able to alter the overall format of the code  per my assignment however, your examples helped me work this into my code the way I'm being asked.  Part of my problem was that I needed numbers.get(line), as opposed to having numbers.get & line as two separate values.  I'm a very visual learner, so this was great and some good overall knowledge too.  Thanks again!

Comment: I could not tell whether you wanted to convert numbers to strings or the reverse.  I see now that your original version was not what you had intended.  Still, most of my comments still apply.

Answer (score 0):

Well that looks like pretty much the example from the Java API itself:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

You can get for "one" the number back by calling:

```
numbers.get("one") //it will return 1
```

if you want to have it the other way arround you have to build it like:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> numbers = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
numbers.put(new Integer(1), "one");
```

and then you will be able to get the number with the text "one"

```
numbers.get(1) //it will return "one"
```

Comment: Ironically, my code posted here is the same as java API - not intentional, the one posted (the first 4 lines) are a school assignment - the rest is what I've added based on direction given to us in the class.  The problem I'm encountering is how to allow the user to input the String and for the program to in turn, output the corresponding Integer.  For example, if the user types "Two", the program should return the corresponding '2'.  I was able to get this working in reverse as your example suggests, but I'm stumped on doing it from String input to proper Integer output.  :-/

Comment: just realized that in my initial post I completely had Integer & String reversed.  Sorry.  It is in fact to input the String and output the integer

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. This helped me to reevaluate my program and identify a few flaws.  :)